# In Socket.IO, is 'heartbeat' an event that can be used to trigger other actions?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, heartbeat

This exact code doesn't work, but, I was hoping something like it was:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('heartbeat', function() {
        // Do something here...
    });
});
```

Is something like this possible? I mean, I know I can just make a different function that triggers every, say, 15 seconds using a setInterval:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    setInterval(function() {
        // Do something
    },15000);
});
```

But since the heartbeat is already running at this interval, why not make use of it?

In any case, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that I see what you're trying to do. There are a few exposed events that you can check here - [list of Socket.io events](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events) - but there is no "heartbeat" event that you can tap into to fire at a set interval.

You're on the right track with the second piece of code -

```
setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('heartbeat', someData);
}, 5000);
```

And on the client side -

```
socket.on('heartbeat', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```