# Socket.io event on heartbeat

Tags: javascript, express, coffeescript, websocket, socket.io

Socket.IO uses heartbeat pattern to be sure that a client is still connected. 
It would solve my algorithm if I would be able to subscribe to the hearbeat event on server.

for instance:
     socket.on "heartbeat", ->
       mycode

any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heartbeat happens very frequently, are you sure that's the right thing? I use the "connect" event, that seems like it might do what you need:

```
  connect: (url, options, connectCallback) =>
    someFunction = =>
      @doSomeRedisStuff() if @connected

    @logger.debug "starting connection to url: #{url}"
    @socket = @socket.connect(url, options)
    @logger.debug "connecting ..."
    @socket.on "connect", =>    
      @logger.info "connected (socket id #{(@socket.socket.sessionid)})"
      @connected = true 
      setTimeout someFunction, 2000
      connectCallback() if connectCallback?
     @socket.on "disconnect", =>
       @connected = false
```

If the connection to the server is interrupted (e.g. the server is restarted) the connect event will kick off when the connection comes back. Socket.IO is smart about this.

Comment: connect if one time per session or per part of the session. When the client has a good network then the connection might last for hours or in my application case days. I would like to know that the connection is alive in the meantime.

Comment: @Luman75 there's a `socket.on 'disconnect', -> ` as well. I'd just store the connection state somewhere and update in those two callbacks.

Comment: of course there is disconnect. But I would like to "poke" some redis variables during the ongoing socket.io connection.

Comment: @Luman75 I think you should set and clear a repeating action with setTimeout in the disconnect/connect callbacks:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440132/in-socket-io-is-heartbeat-an-event-that-can-be-used-to-trigger-other-actions

Comment: Ok. if you call someFunction recursively with some sleep. Then yes, that whould work. Unless memory leakage might be an issue here.

Comment: @Luman75 it's got a 2000 sleep on it, that's where you'd adjust the freq.